# Test for difference of spatial/temporal distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, spatial, spatio-temporal

I have the data of the average hourly consumption of electric power in 50 districst of a city, for the days of 2 months:

```
 DAY HOUR  DISTRICT  E.CONSUM
  1   0      1        127.63
  1   0      2        82.03
 .....
  60  23     50       1.23
```

By some graphical comparison, it is pretty clear to me that the "behaviour" of the city is really different whether the days are working days or not, but I would like to perfomr a test to prove it.

Here's what I tought:

- divide the dataset in 2, Working days and Holidays
- compute the sample mean over the days, in order to obtain 2 "histograms" for each district, one for the Working and another for the Holidays

Now I need to test for the equality of 50 coupled histograms, any idea how to do it?

Any idea on other ways to proceed is really welcome!!

Comment: Hi, nice question! Big data set and simple, clear statistical question. This is a  classic two-way ANOVA setting, but since it's an observational, not experimental, study, this may get messy...in practice, which steps to follow in your analysis, depends a lot on the actual data set. Without the data (at least a random subsample, if you cannot put the full data set somewhere and add a link to your question) it's difficult to answer.